# SQL - How to Calculate Average TargetRate for each project

Tags: sql, group-by, average

Apologies in advance for what might be a basic question. I have a database with projects, and these projects have phases underneath them.

Each of the phases has a target hourly rate we are looking to achieve (this is an entry made into a field named TargetRate). The target rates may be the same or different, and there is one for each phase. I'm trying to get the average of the target rates for the particular project.

Data Set:

| ProjectID | PhaseID | ProjectKey | TargetRate | (Comment) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 500 | 500 | 150 | (Project) |
| 12345 | 501 | 500 | 140 | (Phase 1) |
| 12345 | 502 | 500 | 155 | (Phase 2) |
| 12345 | 503 | 500 | 150 | (Phase 3) |
| 67890 | 100 | 100 | 200 | (another project) |
| 67890 | 101 | 100 | 205 | (Phase 1 of the other project) |

I wrote a simple query

```
SELECT AVG(prj_TargetRate) 
FROM Projects
```

and it seems to return the average for all target rates across all projects. I'm looking to get the average for the rates across a single project.

So, for Project 12345 in the table above, it should return 148.75. How do I tell the formula to evaluate only those rows for the same project ID?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY projectId`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!  I fear we are about to enter the world of "joins", but I'm willing to try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Just add group by clause.

```
select ProjectId, avg(prj_TargetRate) FROM Projects
group by ProjectId
```

Is  the column name `prj_TargetRate`? Or it will be :

```
select ProjectId, avg(TargetRate) FROM Projects
group by ProjectId
```

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 Create table Projects(ProjectID int, PhaseID int, ProjectKey int, TargetRate int, Comment varchar(50));

 insert into Projects values(12345, 500,    500,    150,    'Project');
 insert into Projects values(12345, 501,    500,    140,    'Phase 1');
 insert into Projects values(12345, 502,    500,    155,    'Phase 2');
 insert into Projects values(12345, 503,    500,    150,    'Phase 3');
 insert into Projects values(67890, 100,    100,    200,    'another project');
 insert into Projects values(67890, 101,    100,    205,    'Phase 1 of the other project');
```

Query:

```
 select ProjectId, avg(TargetRate)Average_TargetRate FROM Projects
 group by ProjectId
```

Output:

| ProjectId | Average_TargetRate |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 148 |
| 67890 | 202 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=cefbbe4ba028bd9b2ef5939799731dec)*

Comment: Thank you so much for the education!<br/>

I've attempted this (these are the actual field and table names):<br/>

select avg(prj_TargetRate) FROM AxProject<br/>
group by [Project Key]<br/>

And I receive an error: "Formula is invalid, Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: Sorry for that terrible formatting!  I will read the notes about how to do it properly.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` the `ProjectID` field while selecting the `AVG(TargetRate)`.

```
SELECT 
  ProjectId,
  AVG(TargetRate)AverageTargetRate,
FROM Projects
GROUP BY ProjectId;
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I received the same error as that noted on the other proposed answer.

Comment: I've revised my answer with better table names, that might be the issue.  Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur's answer seems to work, and it's very similar.